# PostgreSQL - insert a row in Table A, then update row in Table B with returned id

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following tables in a Postgres database (trivialized example):

**Table A**

```
person_id    | UNIQUE SERIAL integer
first_name   | text
last_name    | text
full_name_id | integer[]
```

**Table B**

```
full_name_id | UNIQUE SERIAL integer
full_name    | text
```

For each row of Table A, I would like to insert a new row into Table B with `full_name = first_name || last_name`, and update the new `full_name_id` in the corresponding row in Table A.

Is it possible to write a single query that does this?

This is what I have so far (again, trivialized):

```
WITH a AS (
  SELECT first_name, last_name
  FROM table_a
) 
INSERT
  INTO table_b(full_name)
  SELECT first_name || last_name AS full_name
  FROM a
  RETURNING full_name_id;
```

In my real-world scenario, a similar query successfully inserts correct rows in Table B. However, I'm not sure what to do next, to update `full_name_id` in Table A.

Note: the `full_name_id` column in Table A is an array to better reflect my real-world scenario (one row in Table A can reference multiple rows in Table B). To the best of my knowledge, this means I can't use foreign keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do:

```
with i as (
      insert into b (full_name)
          select distinct first_name || ' ' || last_name
          from a
          returning *
    )
update a
    set full_name_id = i.full_name_id
    from i
    where i.full_name = a.first_name || ' ' || a.last_name;
```